# Setting a generic parameter of a class through reflection?

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection, parameters

So before I ask the question, I feel that I must explain my situation for the question to make any logical sense:

I have the generic nested `class` `ThreadHierarchy<P,C extends ExtendedThreadHandler<T>>` (where P represents the parent and C, the child) inside of the generic class `ExtendedThreadHandler<T>` (where T represents type), and I need to create an instance of the `TheradHierarechy` class in the main constructor of its superclass like so:

```
    //Thread State initializer
public ExtendedThreadHandler() {
    this.setThreadClass((T)this);
    this.setThreadName(getClassInstance().getClass().getSimpleName());
    ThreadHierarchy th = new ThreadHierarchy<Thread.currentThread().getClass(), T>(true);
}
```

The issue with this is that while instantiating classes, the generic input values only accept string literals such as the predefined generic type `T` from `ExtendedTheadHandler<T>`, and therefore, I cannot input a method call or variable into the instance parameters.

Is there a way to either:

A) Input return values, in this case a class, into a generic class or method by defining a new instance variable to pass in? (I couldn't figure out how to do this)

OR

B) Use reflection to create an instance of the class where the values of `P` and `C` can be assigned manually?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to assign generic parameters...dynamically?

Comment: That's not possible. Generics are evaluated at compile-time, far too early for any method calls or reflection. Your design also sounds very confusing, so you might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Well I came up with another solution to the problem, however, it involves defining and returning very vague objects. The ideal solution was to return type specific values for functionality and efficiency. What if I used reflection modify the values of the generic variables and then used the reflected object to create a new instance of that class and simply used that instance? Or is this still not possible in Java?

Comment: It's not possible and even if it were, it wouldn't actually make your code any better. How familiar are you with generics? I'm having a hard time seeing what kind of problem you're trying to solve above. Considering that the *advantages* of generics show up at compile-time, trying to put values at run-time would be completely useless.

Comment: Well currently, I am working on a project and most of the classes use generics so I'd say quite well. What I needed for that class specifically was to input the Parent class and child class as generic parameters so that all of the return types and map values would be restricted to the type that was put in at runtime. Now I could remove the generic values and simply substitute an `Object` in place of the value, however, all of the return types would be then allowed to by anything.

Comment: Well, I'd recommend reading some more about generics. Working on a project that uses generics does teach you the basics, but based on some of what you've said you don't have the full picture.

Comment: Alright, well if that's the case, then I will go read more about generics. Thanks for your help.